# Racket conditional sum of series by recursion

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I am new to Racket. I need to sum all the natural numbers less than 1000 (or any nth value) and the numbers will be divisible by 3 or 5. I have a code which can do that but using iteration. But I have to do same thing by recursion. The code is as follows:

```
(define (sum-divisibles limit)
  (for/sum ([i (in-range 1 limit)]
            #:when (or (divides? i 3)
                       (divides? i 5)))
    i))

(define (divides? m n)
  (= 0 (remainder m n)))
```

I need to do same thing but with recursion but not with loop or iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straightforward, as long as you visualize each iteration in the loop as a function call. Think about it: the original `for` loop goes from `1` up to and including `limit-1`. That's the same as starting from `limit-1`, decreasing the limit by `1` at each function call, and stopping when we reach `0`.

There are two important things to remember wen writing recursive procedure:

1. We have to make sure that we stop at some point - this is called the *base case*; for this example, that happens when we reach `0` (because the original loop includes `1`).
2. We have to *combine* the partial results that we obtain along when calling the recursion: if the current number happens to be divisible by `3` or `5` then we add it to the rest of the recursive calls, otherwise we ignore it but keep advancing the recursion anyway, until we reach the base case.

This is what I mean:

```
(define (sum-divisibles limit)
  (cond ((= limit 0) 0)                             ; base case, stop recursion
        ((or (divides? limit 3) (divides? limit 5)) ; does the condition hold?
         (+ limit                                   ; then we add current value
            (sum-divisibles (- limit 1))))          ; and advance the recursion
        (else                                       ; otherwise skip it
         (sum-divisibles (- limit 1)))))            ; and advance the recursion
```

Be careful with the initial `limit` value, remember that in your original code the `limit` *is not* added to the sum (the iteration stops right before reaching it), hence the equivalent way to call the recursive version is this:

```
(sum-divisibles (- n 1))
```

For example, to obtain the same value as `(sum-divisibles 50)` with your code, we have to call it like this in the recursive version:

```
(sum-divisibles 49)
=> 543
```

Alternatively you could write a helper procedure that takes care of decreasing the input `limit` by one before calling the actual recursive procedure, but that's left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @DataPoliceInc. Did this or any of the other answers solve your question? if so, please don't forget to accept and/or upvote the best answers, to encourage the posters ;)

Comment: Hi, Oskar. thank you for you explanation. Now it is very clear to me and I understand everything. Now I am trying to create a Helper Function for (N-1) case that you have said.

Answer (score 1):

Let have `n` be some positive number and `m` is predecessor, `m = n - 1`.

Now, suppose you know that `(sum-divisibles m)` equals some value `s`. How would you do to compute `(sum-divisible n)`?

Try writing a function which takes a value `n` and the value `s`, and computes the sum for `n`.

```
 (define (recur n s) ...)
```

Then you will be able to define `sum-divisibles` in terms of `limit` and the recursive application of `sum-divisibles` for `limit - 1`. You also need to take care of the base case of the recursion, when `limit` is zero.

Answer (score 1):

One can use 'named let' for recursion:

```
(define limit 1000)

(let loop ((n 1)                 ; starting values
           (sum 0))
  (cond
    [(> n limit) sum]            ; print out sum if limit reached;

    [(or (= 0 (modulo n 3))      ; if n is divisible by 3 or 5
         (= 0 (modulo n 5)))
     (loop (add1 n) (+ sum n))]  ; add this number to sum and loop again with next number

    [else                        ; if not divisible
     (loop (add1 n) sum)]        ; loop with next number without adding to sum
    ))
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much. Now it is very clear to me.